# alpha texture not applying on sculpt mesh

Tags: sculpting

is simple, go to texture field right windows red square icon, select the texture, go to sculpt mode select draw brush, go to texture in tool window, select the such texture, try applying it on the mesh and nothing will happen, how could i solve it?

how to sculpt with alphas in blender:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zxbwNfRU4QA

it is for a  school project i have to deliver today

blender file here:

https://workupload.com/archive/mBYE8hU8Gs

just to clarify, my problem is that the alpha texture is doing nothing and i have used it before on other sculpts

what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Hello, it seems to work fine, except the topology is not very good, also maybe set the Stroke to Space instead of Anchored?

Comment: do you think i could fix it by remeshing the dragon?

Comment: tried remeshing, failed

Comment: Yes it seems hard to remesh

Comment: i tried anchored too, but also the texture image is not showing

Comment: maybe it have not solution, should i close this thread and delete it?

Comment: You should retopologize it properly, especially if you plan to animate it. As for the thread, keep it open, maybe someone will propose a solution.

Comment: i need to pose it, not animating for now, im not an animator im a sculptor and modeler for now heheh, thank you for your answer

Comment: To change the pose you could use the Pose brush in Sculpt mode but your topology is bad so it's going to be painful. Why did you begin by sculpting? Begin by modelling your object, not sculpting, you'll try sculpting later.

Comment: by modeling you mean posing it and model it with the pose already? , did not came to my mind and now i am suffering the consecuenses